# How do you keep up with (non-periodical) conference proceedings?

Tags: publications

I am an EE & CS graduate student and [IEEE](https://www.ieee.org/index.html) is a typical and well-known associations.

I am getting papers published in Transactions, Journals Magazines, etc... via RSS feed. For example, [IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=7755) has a [feed](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rss/TOC7755.XML) published once a month.

So far, however, I couldn't find a way to get a list of conference proceeding papers when they are published. As a conference proceeding is not a periodical publication, generally, there is no such *feed* things. Therefore, I have to wait and check everyday until it is published. (Some conference provides papers when conference is being held. But in general, it takes two or three months from the conference to be published.)

Furthermore, [USENIX](https://www.usenix.org/) has a [feed](https://www.usenix.org/blog/rss.xml), but it is not a feed about published papers. USENIX does not provide any feed even for the periodical.

In such situation, how do you keep up with the recent publications?

1. I don't care about the recent publication. I search them on demand.
2. I keep up them manually. (You are a very diligent person. :-> )
3. My organization (university, company) has a sort of curation, curator.
4. None of them. Other ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about EE, but for Computer Science, most of the venues you would usually want to track are listed in [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de). DBLP itself does, as far as I know, not offer a subscription service, but (behold the beauty of open data) somebody else has built [RSS feeds for DBLP](http://services.ceon.pl/dblpfeeds/).

This would allow you to use your favorite newsreader to keep up with conference publications the same way you are already tracking journals.

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-answer, but, assuming you have a personal account (free to create), IEEEXplore (which costs a small fortune to any university) has a [very limited interface to receive alerts for **all conferences**](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conf_tocalerts.jsp) as a content alert on a weekly basis. I truly wonder who subscribes to this, as it must be information overload!

[image: Weekly subscription to ALL conferences]

It's a shame, because the periodical interface to receive content alerts is not bad:

[image: Subscription to Journals and Magazines]